# understandin EaayQuery how it is pulling data from sql server

Tags: sql, easyquery

I need some help understanding how easy query executes a query in which table name seems to be prefixed with eq.Sometable.
Now in database there is no schema eq nor there is a table by name Somerable. But I looked at query in profiler, and then ran it in management studio. Query works.
I am hoping some one can let me know how sql server knows what easyquery means and shows results.
I have never come accross easyquery and have been given a task where have to fix something. Hope some one can shed some light
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it is using synonyms (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Or maybe just an alias. Try posting the query too so we can take a look?

Comment: Query is simple such as select distinct abc.col1 as col1, abc.col2 as col2 from eq.query as abc